# Rolling my own CMS with the WCF, what should my contract be?

Tags: wcf, content-management-system, datacontract

I'm looking to create a solution for a asp.net mvc app that displays unstructured course descriptions that have been scraped from around the web. The web server will be on a web hosting company while the description db will be on a private network, so I'd like to pass the  description to the mvc app through a WCF service. For the body of the description do I just want to use a string property...

```
public class CourseDescription {

    // data fields
    public string CourseTitle { get; set; }
    public int Days { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> UpcomingDates { get; set; }

    // html properties
    public string Keywords { get;  set;}
    public string HtmlDescription { get; set; }

}
```

... or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is unstructured text, a string is fine.